# 2019 survey: unclear question about salary

Tags: support, survey-2019

The wording is:

> What is your current total compensation (salary, bonuses, and perks, before taxes and deductions), in EUR European Euro? Please enter a whole number in the box below, without any punctuation. If you are paid hourly, please estimate an equivalent weekly, monthly, or yearly salary. If you prefer not to answer, please leave the box empty.

How to specify that what I write is per year / per month / per week? I mean, this cannot be deduced: some people could earn in a month what some other people earn in a week.

Comment: Came here precisely to ask this. This questions is very confusing.

Comment: I filled out the development survey only for this, the question seems to be fixed.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The question asks for a *"weekly, monthly,* ***or*** *yearly"* salary, so any of these is fine.

The next question asks over which period the number you provided applies to.

---

IMO the two questions should have been provided on the same page as they directly relate to each other and the wording of the first question (the one mentioned in this question) doesn't perfectly describe what is requested.

Comment: We were able to change our survey logic so that the questions about salary, time period and # of hours you work now show on one page. Thx for bringing to our attention

Comment: I think saying only the amount and not the time quanta for which it is earned, is a huge information loss and makes the obvious intent of the question practically unreachable. Although saying only the amount, the time period can be estimated, for example if someone says "60", then it is probably hourly and in USD/EUR. Maybe a better question had been the total amount of money we've earned last year by programming.